# Two dice are rolled and the sum of the face values is less than six. What is the probability that at least one of the dice came up a four?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this puzzle. There are 10 possible cases with a sum smaller than 6. This results 10/36 = 5/18.

4/10 * 3/10 * 2/10 for the 10 cases.

(4,1) (4,1) / (4,1) (4,1) + (2,2) = 2/3 (at least four , sum = 5)

I don't know how to apply the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about applying formulas or anything like that. Let's look at this intuitively.

As you stated, there are 10 possible cases with a sum smaller than six. I will list them out here.
$$1,1\\
1,2\\
1,3\\
\color{red}{1,4}\\
2,1\\
2,2\\
2,3\\
3,1\\
3,2\\
\color{red}{4,1}
$$
As you can see, in only two of these $10$ cases, which each happen with the same probability, the $4$ shows up. Thus the chance of one of the dice being a four given that the sum is less than $6$ is simply $2/10 = .2$ chance.

Answer (score 0):

So, count the number of ways to roll less than a six. Then count the number of those rolls that have a $4$. The ratio of these two numbers is the answer.

Alternatively, you can use the formula $P(A\land B)=P(A|B)P(B)$. Letting $A=$"there is a $4$" and letting $B=$"less than $6$" we see that you can easily calculate both $P(A\land B)$ and $P(B)$, so taking their ratio gives $P(A|B)$. Notice that this is the same computation as described above. However, in some cases doing it one way vs doing it another has advantages.